# I have jenkins jobs running on ec2 machine i want to migrate all the jobs in to docker container

Tags: jenkins, devops

I have jenkins jobs running on ec2 machine. how to migrate all the jobs in to docker container?

Comment: Yes,if you're moving to docker - try a modern docker-based CI/CD tool like https://codefresh.io.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the entire `$JENKINS_HOME` from your ec2 instance to the `$JENKINS_HOME` of the container (or just certain directories, e.g. `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs` to the containers `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs` directory).

Using `docker-compose` and assuming `${PWD}/ec2` contains a copy of the `$JENKINS_HOME` from my ec2 instance:

```
version: '3'
services:
  filtering:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/ec2:/var/jenkins_home
```

Using just `docker`: `docker run -v ${PWD}/ec2:/var/jenkins_home -p 8080:8080 jenkins/jenkins:lts`

**Note**: mounting the entire `$JENKINS_HOME` has the advantage of keeping certain config that resides outside of the `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs` directory such as the `$JENKINS_HOME/nodes`.

Comment: Thank you so much i will check and let you know if i have any questions.

Comment: @EswanthReddy for sure, e.g. am migrating my Jenkins to a `docker` mounting the entire `$JENKINS_HOME`. So far have had to extend the image with my build requirements (i.e. `maven`, `ansible`, etc.) and have updated the system config with the new hostname - seems legit.

Comment: I will try and let you know