# Put already existing jenkins into docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have Jenkins configured with lots of jobs that I would like to put into Docker container.
Is there a easy way to do such thing?

PS I'm completely new to docker, therefore good guide would be great.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54441051/1423507) should help with that.

Comment: I will try, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Had to do the same some month ago.

I used ThinBackup to extract the complete jenkins_home and move it to another server. This can be mounted inside a docker container and your Jenkins should work as before. But since your old Jenkins is still running there is no risk if it should fail for some reason.

You can follow this (where jenkins-data is the backup):
https://medium.com/@chrisemerson/first-time-setup-with-jenkins-on-docker-f0632dce9853

If you use Docker inside Jenkins you have to mount the docker.sock of the host as well, if not you can leave out that part.